# how to print the json response in jquery

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

below is the response im getting from server side. how to handle this response to display in ui

```
dataset=[
    [0, " ", "PORT","1", " ", "", "false", "false", 0, true, -1, true, ''],
    [1, " ", "PORT","5", " ", "", "false", "false", 0, true, -1, false, ''], 
    [2, " ", "PORT","7", " ", "", "false", "false", 0, true, -1, true, ''],
    [3, " ", "PORT","3", " ", "", "false", "false", 0, true, -1, true, ''],
    [4, " ", "PORT","1", " ", "", "false", "false", 0, true, -1, false, '']
   ];
```

this is looking like array. so i dont know how to print this. please anyone help on this

Comment: This is not JSON this is an array.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mentioned above is not JSON, It's kind of array.

And for array you can do below code to print the data.

```
var arrayLength = dataset.length;
for(var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    console.log(dataset[i]);
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/a5zap336/)

```
var dataset=[
[0, " ", "PORT","1", " ", "", "false", "false", 0, true, -1, true, ''],
[1, " ", "PORT","5", " ", "", "false", "false", 0, true, -1, false, ''], 
[2, " ", "PORT","7", " ", "", "false", "false", 0, true, -1, true, ''],
[3, " ", "PORT","3", " ", "", "false", "false", 0, true, -1, true, ''],
[4, " ", "PORT","1", " ", "", "false", "false", 0, true, -1, false, '']
];
  $.each(dataset,function(index,value){
    $.each(value,function(index,value){
        alert(value);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@Zubair might have better answer but just in case you're really getting the whole thing with the `dataset` variable, here's a demo:

### [Demo](http://jsbin.com/bagafo/edit?html,output)

```
var response = 'var dataset = [[0, " ", "PORT","1", " ", "", "false", "false", 0, true, -1, true, ''],[1, " ", "PORT","5", " ", "", "false", "false", 0, true, -1, false, ''], [2, " ", "PORT","7", " ", "", "false", "false", 0, true, -1, true, ''],[3, " ", "PORT","3", " ", "", "false", "false", 0, true, -1, true, ''],[4, " ", "PORT","1", " ", "", "false", "false", 0, true, -1, false, '']];';

eval(response);

$.each(dataset, function(i,l){
  $('body').append(l + "<br>")
});
```

### Result:

```
0, ,PORT,1, ,,false,false,0,true,-1,true,
1, ,PORT,5, ,,false,false,0,true,-1,false,
2, ,PORT,7, ,,false,false,0,true,-1,true,
3, ,PORT,3, ,,false,false,0,true,-1,true,
4, ,PORT,1, ,,false,false,0,true,-1,false,
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title> 
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var dataset = [
    [0, " ", "PORT", "1", " ", "", "false", "false", 0, true, -1, true, ''],
    [1, " ", "PORT", "5", " ", "", "false", "false", 0, true, -1, false, ''],
    [2, " ", "PORT", "7", " ", "", "false", "false", 0, true, -1, true, ''],
    [3, " ", "PORT", "3", " ", "", "false", "false", 0, true, -1, true, ''],
    [4, " ", "PORT", "1", " ", "", "false", "false", 0, true, -1, false, '']
];
jQuery.each(dataset, function (index, val) {
    //$("#" + val).text("Mine is " + val + ".");
    jQuery.each(val, function (elindex, elval) {
        console.log(index+":->" + elval);
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```